# Среднее значение всех ключей во вложенном словаре

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

Есть словарь со вложенной структурой, необходимо найти среднее значение ключей a,b,c,d по ключу.

```
dict =  {'one': {'a': 0.3, 'b': 0.4, 'c': 0.4, 'd': 0.2}, 'two': {'a': 0.2, 'b': 0.3, 'c': 0.5, 'd': 0.2}, ' three': {'a': 0.3, 'b': 0.2, 'c': 0.3, 'd': 0.3}, 'four': {'a': 0.1, 'b': 0.6, 'c': 0.5, 'd': 0.1}}
```

Что я хочу получить:

```
new_dict =  {'one': 0,325, 'two': 0.3,' three': 0.275, 'four': 0.325}
```

Подскажите, как такое сделать? Я новичок, пытаюсь написать цикл, но выходит совсем не то.

Есть идея использовать mean(), но не понимаю как

```
new_dict = {idx: {key: mean(idx) for key, idx in j.items()} for idx, j in dict.items()}
```

Comment: >Я новичок, пытаюсь написать цикл, но выходит совсем не то.
Покажите

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов new_dict = {idx: {key: mean(idx) for key, idx in j.items()} for idx, j in dict.items()}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {
    'one': {'a': 0.3, 'b': 0.4, 'c': 0.4, 'd': 0.2},
    'two': {'a': 0.2, 'b': 0.3, 'c': 0.5, 'd': 0.2},
    ' three': {'a': 0.3, 'b': 0.2, 'c': 0.3, 'd': 0.3},
    'four': {'a': 0.1, 'b': 0.6, 'c': 0.5, 'd': 0.1}
}

new_d = dict()
for name, sub_dict in d.items():
    values = sub_dict.values()
    new_d[name] = sum(values) / len(values)
print(new_d)
# {'one': 0.325, 'two': 0.3, ' three': 0.275, 'four': 0.325}
```

С функцией `mean`:

```
from statistics import mean

new_d = {name: mean(sub_dict.values()) for name, sub_dict in d.items()}
print(new_d)
# {'one': 0.325, 'two': 0.3, ' three': 0.275, 'four': 0.325}
```

Comment: Не `4`, а `len(sub_dict.values())`

Comment: @CrazyElf, так то их всегда 4, плюс не хотелось два раза вызывать `.values()`, поэтому и добавил второй вариант с `mean` :)

Comment: Ладно, но выглядит странно, когда числитель универсальный `sum`, а знаменатель фиксированный. Так то пофик, конечно )

Comment: @CrazyElf, ну да... Самому это глаз цепляет :) Подправлю :)

Answer (score 1):

```
new_dict = {}
for i, j in my_dict.items():
    new_dict[i] = sum(j.values()) / len(j.values())
print(new_dict)
```

Вот готовый цикл

Comment: Не 4, а `len(j.values())`

Comment: @CrazyElf В вопросе написано именно про 4 элемента - a, b, c, d.

Comment: В данном случае да. Я просто как профессионал вижу "магические константы" в коде, а это анти-паттерн )